# IGNORE RESULTS IF A COLUMN HAS THE SAME VALUE - ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written a SQL query to display results, the below is the query

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID, INVOICE_NO, MOBILE_NO, ITEM_AMOUT
FROM INVOICE_DAILY_DTS
WHERE DAILY_DTS != 200 AND INVOICE_SAM = 12;
```

When I am executing the above query, I am getting the below results

```
1) 11331133114, 154245, 077123456789, 579.5
2) 11331133114, 154245, 077123456789, 579.5
3) 11331133114, 154246, 077457852155, 780.4
4) 11331133114, 154245, 077123456789, 579.5
5) 11331133114, 154458, 077547822554, 900.0
6) 11331133114, 154245, 077123456789, 579.5
7) 11331133114, 154246, 077457852155, 780.4
```

If you see the above results table has multiple rows of data in the INVOICE_NO column, I suggest getting ignore 2,4,6 & 7th rows when executing the query.
Simple if the INVOICE_NO is duplicated only needs to get the first row of the result and ignore other results.

I am expecting the results are below, where it has ignored or excepted the results and showing the first row only of each INVOCIE_NO

```
1) 11331133114, 154245, 077123456789, 579.5
2) 11331133114, 154246, 077457852155, 780.4
3) 11331133114, 154458, 077547822554, 900.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Duplicate rows in Oracle](/q/816851/90527)", "[How do I prevent the loading of duplicate rows in to an Oracle table?](/q/1588588/90527)", "[Removing duplicate rows from table in Oracle](/q/529098/90527)", "[Identifying duplicates in a table without index](/q/2495552/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INVOICE_NO, TRANSACTION_ID, MOBILE_NO, ITEM_AMOUT
FROM INVOICE_DAILY_DTS
WHERE DAILY_DTS != 200 AND INVOICE_SAM = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [row_number()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) to do it

```
SELECT t.TRANSACTION_ID, t.INVOICE_NO, t.MOBILE_NO, t.ITEM_AMOUT
 FROM
 (
  SELECT TRANSACTION_ID, INVOICE_NO, MOBILE_NO, ITEM_AMOUT,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INVOICE_NO) rn
 FROM INVOICE_DAILY_DTS
 WHERE DAILY_DTS != 200 AND INVOICE_SAM = 12
 ) AS t
WHERE t.rn=1
```